# InversifyJS purpose of using .toConstantValue

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs, inversify-binding-decorators

We already have inSingletonScope in Insersify JS. What is the purpose of using .toConstantValue? Could anyone let me know when do we want to use .toConstantValue?

Comment: You can find here https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/89ecfd7cf8270ec77ea4a896d5519c6ab92d8161/wiki/recipes.md some recipes

Comment: I saw that. I just don't understand why we bind a container to a constant?